# pyarrow: Parse non-standard date

Tags: timestamp, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a CSV file with columns using nonstandard date format that requires a little cleaning. How can I parse this into pyarrow and write to parquet? The format is either:

- `%Y%m%d` ex: `19991231`
- `%Y%m00` ex: `19991200` (Year and month, but no day specified)
- `%Y0000` ex: `19990000` (Only year specified)
- `0` or blank for unknown.

I want to be able to parse these all into a date (or timestamp) type. The last option (`0` or blank) should always become a null value. I'm happy to treat `%Y%m00` as being the first day of that month and `%Y0000` as first day of that year (or some similar default assumption).

I tried using `pyarrow.csv.read_csv()` with `convert_options=pyarrow.csv.ConvertOptions(timestamp_parsers=["%Y%m%d", "%Y%m00", "%Y0000"])`, but this led to `pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: In CSV column #16: CSV conversion error to timestamp[s]: invalid value '0'`.

I'm happy to do this conversion either at loading time or afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll be able to get `pyarrow.csv.read_csv` to support this.

However you can load the date column as strings and convert it later using [`pyarrow.compute`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/compute.html)

```
import pyarrow.csv
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow as pc

table = pyarrow.csv.read_csv 

# Get the date column
array = table['my_date_column'].combine_chunks()
# Replace string ending with 0000
array = pc.replace_substring_regex(array, "0000$", "0101")
# Replace string ending with 00
array = pc.replace_substring_regex(array, "00$", "01")
# Replace string equal to "0" with null
array = pc.replace_with_mask(array, pc.equal(array, "0"), pa.scalar(None, pa.string()))
# Convert to timestamp
array = pc.strptime(array, format="%Y%m%d", unit='s')
# Convert to date
array = array.cast(pa.date32())
# Put back in the table
table = table.set_column(table.schema.get_field_index("my_date_column"), "my_date_column", array)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, I really appreciate the detailed explanation!